# Implementing a "primitve" version of NavigationPage for ContentView - Performance issue

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an application in which there's the Main Page that holds a header, a footer, and a dynamic ConventView in the centre.

Depends on the button that was clicked (either in the footer or inside the page that is shown in the contentview) the view in the ContentView is updated/changed.
Thus, I needed to make the ContentView act as a bindable control.

To make it work, I maintain in the ViewModel of the MainPage, a stack of tuples .

Every time the content should be changed in the ContentView, I push the current BindingContext (some ViewModel instance) into that stack, paired with the page that is currently displayed in the ContentView. (or pop from the stack if I need to go back to the previous view)
After that, I set the ContentView to the requested View with its matching ViewModel as the BindingContext.

I noticed that the procedure of changing the BindingContext - is a performance issue. most of the time, changing the BindingContext can take 4-6 seconds(!!).
How can I solve this performance problem (without destroying the navigation mechanism I built)?

Thanks,

Comment: Directly do the binding in your ContentView XAML so it initializes with the view itself

Comment: @G.hakim Again, the ContentView's view as always changed on user's click. everytime the user clicks on some button, ContentView's view changed and its binding context changes to new view's ViewModel.

Comment: Just tell me something every view has a single binding context right, What I mean by that is ContentViewA and ViewModelA are linked ContentViewB and ViewModelB are linked and so on and so forth